# C# RSA custom private and public key

Tags: c#, .net, rsa, key-pair

Can I use my own private key and public key(string) on RSA? how?

I want to set String `"aaaa|bbbb|cccc|dddd"` to public key and `"eee|ffff|gggg|hhhh"` to private key.

is that possible?

Comment: put what have you tried and where you got error, can something be happen ? is not the correct type of question, try to find yourself first if that can happen or not

Comment: This is somewhat similar to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569349/ability-to-derive-public-key-from-passphrase - the answer I got was "no, kind of."

Comment: Other than creating an RSA keypair and simply mapping those two strings to the public and private keys (using, say, a Dictionary object), no, it's not possible.